# Profile Image won't display after loading from local storage using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm very new to ReactJs and working on a project that uploads an image data file, converts it to a url, and stores it to localStorage.  Upon choosing the file, the image is displayed.  This part is working.

However, when I try to redisplay the file using localStorage.getItem("ProfileImage"), the image will not display.  In addition, if I do a hard refresh even the state resets and the image preview disappears.  Wondering if anyone can help tell me where I may be going wrong:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class ProfilePhoto extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            imgUrl: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ProfileImage")) || []
        }
    }

    handleImageUpload = function (e) {

        //get the image file
        const selectedFile = e.target.files[0]

        //need to convert to acceptable format for posting...
        const imgData = window.URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile)

        //const ActiveUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ActiveUser"))

        localStorage.setItem("ProfileImage", JSON.stringify(imgData))

        this.setState({
            imgUrl: imgData
        })

        console.log(imgData)

    }.bind(this)

    handleImageSave = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Your profile image has saved!")

    }.bind(this)

    componentDidMount() {

     let ProfileImage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ProfileImage"))
     console.log(ProfileImage)

    }


    render() {

        return (
            <div className="profile-photo">
                <div className="img-preview">
                    <img src={this.state.imgUrl} alt="" />
                </div>

                <form id="myPhotoForm" name="myPhotoForm" onSubmit={this.handleImageSave}>
                    <input type="file" id="imgUrl" name="imgUrl" onChange={this.handleImageUpload} />
                    <button type="submit" value="Submit!">Upload</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ProfilePhoto
```

Comment: what do you get when you log imageUrl and image data

Comment: @nishant console.log(imgData) = blob:http://localhost:3000/848cd2f3-cee4-46cc-8037-9e9e2d121f8f  console.log(this.state.imgUrl) =blob:http://localhost:3000/2c53d039-ca22-4a69-b79b-1aae9f372a68

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
localStorage.setItem("ProfileImage", JSON.stringify(imgData).blob)
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  now my data won't save to local storage.

Comment: sorry i mistake  replace this let ProfileImage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ProfileImage").blob)

Comment: try this let ProfileImage = localStorage.getItem("ProfileImage").substring(5)

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work as well.  console.log(imgData) = :http://localhost:3000/a08f4824-cef2-415d-864c-bd4b9e346537"